# XFCE: hide desktop icons on one monitor (and keep them on another)

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce

I have a dualhead setup with XFCE (based on `ZaphodHeads` Intel mode), currently icon sets are completely identical for both monitors (so if I add or delete something, the displayed icons are always in sync).

Also if I run something like:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -np '/desktop-icons/style' -t int -s 0
```

then it affects both screens. And the structure of `xfce4-desktop.xml` doesn't suggest it can be done on a per-monitor basis.

What I'm after is completely hiding icons on the secondary screen while keeping them on the primary one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that by switching to `metacity` as the default window manager (from `xfwm4`). There's no icon on the second monitor with Metacity.